# Is posible to enable primefaces button after successful validation?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Is posible to enable primefaces button depending on the correct validation of inputText and without using jquery or writing the validation on a java class?
I just looking for enable it in the view side and using several inputTexts
I am trying with `disabled="#{not facesContext.postback or not facesContext .validationFailed}"`
But maybe I am doing something wrong becouse is not working as I`m expecting.
I have something like these but with 4 more inputTexts with similar code.

```
    <p:inputText id="user" value="#{acc.user}" 
        required="true">
        <f:validateLength ... for="user" />
        <p:ajax update="msgUser" event="keyup" />
        <p:ajax update=":#{p:component('add')}"  />
    </p:inputText>
<p:commandButton id="add" update="dataTable"
    oncomplete="addConfirm.hide()" actionListener="#{managedBean.onCreate}" 
    disabled="#{not facesContext.postback or not facesContext .validationFailed}"/>
```

It is all inside a confirmDialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just let the input ajax-update the button wherein you check in its `disabled` attribute if the current request is a postback whereby validation is failed.

```
<p:inputText ...>
    <p:ajax ... update="button" />
</p:inputText>
<p:commandButton id="button" ... disabled="#{not facesContext.postback or not facesContext .validationFailed}" />
```

Comment: Let them do the same.

Comment: It is not working for me, when I write some valid string in one of the inputTexts the commandButton is enabled.

Comment: Put `process="@form"` in `<p:ajax>` or at least those client IDs of specific input fields.

Comment: @ihebiheb: Not sure what you're talking about. That's already covered by the answer.